# auto_route tab navigation on the flutter_platform_widgets PlatformTabScaffold

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-navigation, multiplatform

How can I integrate tab navigation with nested routes using [auto_route](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library) lib on [flutter_platform_widgets](https://github.com/stryder-dev/flutter_platform_widgets) lib [PlatformTabScaffold](https://github.com/stryder-dev/flutter_platform_widgets/wiki/Platform-Widget-Catalog#platform-tab-scaffold)?

I prepared the route definition:

```dart
@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Screen,Route')
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {

  @override
  final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
    AdaptiveRoute(
        initial: true,
        page: HomeRoute.page,
        path: '/home',
        guards: [AuthGuard()],
        children: [
             AdaptiveRoute(page: BalanceRoute.page, path: ''),
             AdaptiveRoute(page: HistoryRoute.page, path: 'history'),
             AdaptiveRoute(page: AccountSettingsRoute.page, path: 'account-settings'),
        ]),
  ];
}
```

However I could not realize where should I apply `AutoTabsRouter`?

```dart
  final items = (BuildContext context, L10n l10n) {
    final icons = [
      context.platformIcons.home,
      context.platformIcons.ellipsis,
      context.platformIcons.accountCircle
    ];

    return List<int>.generate(3, (index) => index)
        .map((i) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)!.primaryColor,
              label: l10n.s(titles[i]),
              icon: Icon(icons[i]),
            ))
        .toList();
  };

  late List<Widget> tabs;

...

    return PlatformTabScaffold(
      iosContentPadding: true,
      tabController: tabController,
      appBarBuilder: (_, index) => PlatformAppBar(...),
      bodyBuilder: (context, index) => IndexedStack(
        index: index,
        children: tabs,
      ),
      items: items(context, l10n),
    );
```

I tried

```dart
 bodyBuilder: (context, index) => AutoTabsRouter(routes:  tabs)
```

But obviously it does not work because there is no connection with tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route')
class $AppRouter {
  @initial
  AutoTabsRouter appTabsRouter;

  BalancePage balancePage;

  HistoryPage historyPage;

  AccountSettingsPage accountSettingsPage;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: AppRouter().delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: AppRouter().defaultRouteParser(),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      builder: (context, router) {
        return PlatformTabScaffold(
          iosContentPadding: true,
          tabController: router.routerState.activeRoute.data as TabController,
          appBarBuilder: (_, index) => PlatformAppBar(...),
          bodyBuilder: (context, index) => AutoTabsScaffold(
            controller: router.routerState.activeRoute.data as AutoTabsRouterController,
            tabs: [
              const AutoRoute(
                initialRoute: 'balance',
                routes: [BalanceRoute()],
              ),
              const AutoRoute(
                initialRoute: 'history',
                routes: [HistoryRoute()],
              ),
              const AutoRoute(
                initialRoute: 'accountSettings',
                routes: [AccountSettingsRoute()],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          items: items(context, l10n),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks very promising but it does not work. The `AutoTabsScaffold` does not have such parameters. And the definition of AppRouter looks strange.
Quite possibly that could work with old versions of `auto_route`. Since v6 it was changed pretty much. And I'm using the latest one: `auto_route: 7.4.0`

Comment: @engilyin you are correct.  `AutoTabsScaffold` widget now takes a `controller` property instead of a `routes`. i made fix

Comment: it is not only problem. E.g. `PlatformTabScaffold` must have own `items` otherwise you get the error. tabs is not a parameter for AutoTabsScaffold